# Cannot add extra scope when running Datastore Wordcount Example

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-dataflow

I am attempting to run the [DatastoreWordCountExample](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/dataflow/examples/DatastoreWordCount.java) from the Dataflow SDK.

The instructions indicate that I should run the following commands:

$ export CLOUDSDK_EXTRA_SCOPES=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/datastore
$ gcloud auth login

However, when I do, I receive the following error:

```
$ export CLOUDSDK_EXTRA_SCOPES=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/datastore
$ gcloud auth login
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/brian/opt/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/gcloud/gcloud.py", line 91, in <module>
    from googlecloudsdk.calliope import base
  File "/Users/brian/opt/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/base.py", line 8, in <module>
    from googlecloudsdk.calliope import usage_text
  File "/Users/brian/opt/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/usage_text.py", line 12, in <module>
    from googlecloudsdk.calliope import arg_parsers
  File "/Users/brian/opt/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/arg_parsers.py", line 42, in <module>
    from googlecloudsdk.core import log
  File "/Users/brian/opt/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/core/log.py", line 12, in <module>
    from googlecloudsdk.core import properties
  File "/Users/brian/opt/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/core/properties.py", line 10, in <module>
    from googlecloudsdk.core import config
  File "/Users/brian/opt/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/core/config.py", line 293, in <module>
    _CheckForExtraScopes()
  File "/Users/brian/opt/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/core/config.py", line 291, in _CheckForExtraScopes
    CLOUDSDK_SCOPES.extend(extra_scopes.split())
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'extend'
```

Note that gcloud runs find as long as CLOUDSDK_EXTRA_SCOPES is unset in my environment variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://code.google.com/p/google-cloud-sdk/issues/detail?id=128 it seems that you no longer need to set this variable for datastore to work. Can you please try that and tell us if it doesn't work?

(meanwhile I'll update the docs)

Comment: Yes, this worked. It allowed me to execute the DatastoreWordCount example using DirectPipelineRunner, but not BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner.

Comment: Thanks. What is the error you're having when running with BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner?

Comment: Jkff, I've tracked the error I was having to the Datastore API. I was receiving an authentication error. I suspect that the issue is due to a warning in the Datastore Documentation that says the project being used must be created with the new console. It is possible that the projects I'm testing were created with the old console. Everything works find with a newly created project. An unfortunate limitation, but one that is possible to overcome.